# Adding and Editing Excel table to the data frame

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, table, excel

1. I have few excel tables of almost 5-6 columns and i need to paste them at different locations in the same map.
2. The values in the excel table gets revised every quarter and i need to edit the table.

Please don't confuse it with the attribute table. I have attached the way it look in the arcmap and the excel table. Help me in figuring out a solution for the same.

Suggest me way by which i dont have to copy/paste the table each time.
Is there a way to edit the table[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you try something? Not sure if this will work! Open one of those spreadsheets and highlight the cells you want then copy (ctrl+c) them. Then go to ArcMap and paste (ctrl+v) into the Layout. Save ArcMap and close. Open the copy and pasted excel spreadsheet (if you closed it), make some changes, save and close, open ArcMap and see if those changes are there. You can sometimes double-click those added spreadsheet tables in ArcGIS and it opens in Excel for editing.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but this didnt work :(

Answer (score 1):

You can copy/paste the cells from Excel to the layout in ArcMap but they will be saved as an image, you won't be able to edit them.
Two other options:

1. (my prefered one) Add the Excel file via the main menu > Insert > Object. Choose the "Create from file" option and browse to your Excel file. This will add the first sheet if there are several sheets in the file. The table is then 'saved' in the mxd, changes to the original table won't be reflected. But you can open and edit the table in Excel by double-clicking it in ArcMap.
2. Add the Excel sheet to the Table of Contents. Open the table and click 'Add table to layout' from the Table Options menu (top left button in the table window). Using this method the link with the original table is preserved, but the table appears as ArcMap understands it (e.g. a header is required on top of each column, if there's none like in your exemple it adds F1 or F2).

Comment: Hi GISGe, your tips are working, but see the images i have attached here and help me out to edit the tables. Also is there is a option to ungroup the attached table?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. To "ungroup" the tables you should put the them in separate Excel sheets with the 2nd option and in separate files with the first one. Then add them once at a time to ArcMap. Which option have you chosen to add the table to ArcMap? With the first one, if you want to edit the table double-click it in ArcMap, and it will open in Excel. With the 2nd one, you can just edit the original table (you'll probably have locks between Excel and ArcMap).

Comment: You have understood it correct. And I am using the first option since i want to create a link between arcmap and excel. But I don't want to create multiple sheets, then i need to create almost 40 sheets. Is there any option with arctoolbox?

Comment: I don't think so. ArcGIS considers an Excel sheet as one table, and anyway I don't see how it could figure out what the structure of your multiple tables is as they're not regular... Be careful, the link with your original file isn't maintained with the first option, but you can still open the tables in Excel FROM ARCMAP.