# Adding Table to Layout View using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, table, layouts

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 and I have a non-spatial table and some layers in a Data Frame.

When I switch to Layout View I want to be able to show the map in a data frame element and the table in another element (something that one could do with "Add Table To Layout" from Table Options, but I want to do this in one step without having to go to Table Options).

Is there a way to do this using ArcPy?

I couldn't find any function in the ArcPy library that would create a new Layout Element ... and then I also don't know how to add the contents of the table to the Layout Element.

Comment: you can look at the second part of my answer here : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81986/need-help-to-automatize-report-generation , but this is meant for automation, not for interactivity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible to create a new Layout Element from scratch using ArcPy but since ArcGIS 10.1 you have been able to clone graphic and text elements.

In the [GraphicElement (arcpy.mapping)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000040000000) help there is code that shows you how to use cloning to:

> construct a graphic table based on data values from a table in the map
>   document.

If you are not keen on using ArcPy to do this then there are a number of ArcGIS Ideas to which I recommend that you add your vote:

- [Dynamic Attribute Table in Layout for Data Driven Page](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bsbCAAQ)
- [Increase User Control of Tables Added to Layout](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=0873000000087SWAAY)
- [Table element in the layout by default](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000buxWAAQ)