# How to convert picture to annotation in ArcGIS 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, convert, table, annotation, excel

I have been tasked to display analytical data tables (currently in MS Excel) in an ArcGIS (v 10.1) map document (.mxd) and would also like to convert them to map document annotation, if possible.  Ideally, I would like the embedded excel tables to stay the same size and in the same place when I am moving and zooming around the map document.  Each analytical table is linked to a specific monitoring well.

If I simply cut-and-paste the individual tables (e.g. below) into my map, they will appear as "pictures".  I know that pictures are neither graphics (point, line, polygon, text) nor a feature.  And when I right-click on the pasted table, I am not allowed to "Convert to Graphics" (as it is greyed out).  How can I solve this problem?  Is there a work-around?

**Example table I want to add to my map document (which appears as a picture in ArcGIS):**

[image]

Comment: You may need to look into http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85592/how-to-add-table-to-layout-view-using-arcpy

Comment: After reading what Graphic.Element arcpy mapping does, it seems that I should actually be using Picture.Element since I have a picture, not a graphic.  Even so, I think this may be too complicated and perhaps not worth developing a python script for.  It is hard to visualize the end result of the example provided in the ArcGIS Help 10.1.  Anyway, I updated my image (above) to show you what I want to display.  Right now, it is simply a copy/paste of the Excel table(s) with individual lines drawn to each relevant well.

Comment: Another complication is that the table I am including is not simply arranged so that each column is a unique field.  That is, the first column includes the monitoring well number and below that are the chemical names - not related.