# tables printed on separate layout page using data driven pages in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages

I have 150 layout views made by the data driven page function in ArcMap. I also created dynamic tables with the production mapping extension. In some cases the tables are too big for my layout view, so I want to use data driven pages to print the dynamic tables on the other side of the paper. Is it possible to create this?

I found this article: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/building-map-books-with-arcgis.htm but this is more usefull for external documents, not the dynamic attribute table from ArcMap itself.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible to do this using ArcPy for both ArcGIS Desktop (and ArcGIS Pro) but I think using Data Driven Pages (and Map Series) can get in the way of flexibility.  Instead I prefer to visit the features to create map and any supporting pages (like dynamic tables) by iterating a Search Cursor.

The coding patterns are similar to those linked from [Inserting supporting pages into your map book](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/inserting-non-map-pages-into-your-map-book.htm).

In the past I have done the dynamic table part using [ReportLab](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reportlab) but using the [cloning of text and graphic elements](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/85597/115) is an alternative way.

As an aside there is another (and I think "best yet") way, which I have seen no one else use.  I am planning to release a comprehensive [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?q=arcpy) eLearning video that teaches this technique for ArcGIS Pro in about 3 weeks time.  Consequently, I would prefer not to describe that here just yet.  Much of that technique is equally applicable to using ArcPy with ArcMap.